# Flask python cannot access public resource

Tags: flask, cpanel, host

Context:
On my cPanel environment I have a file called `home.php`, this file contain following code:

```
<?php
// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit;
}
?>
....html code irelevant........
```

In this cPanel environment I also set up a Python app through Flask. Main code of this Python app is store in `app.py` that contains this code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def passguide_fct():
    message = ""  # Initialize an empty message variable

    if request.method == "POST":
        password = generatepassword()
        message = password

    return render_template('passguide.html', password=message)
```

passguide.html contains also irelevant html code

Problem is if I want to include same PHP code in this `passguide.html` it doesn't work as expected. I also renamed here in `app.py` from `passguide.html` to `passguide.php` and include PHP code and I have same problem.

I test with a blank Flask function and try to access file from `public_html` from Flask function and it appear I cannot access it directly.

What can I do in this situation? Should I change something in my site's `.htaccess` or modify my Flask function to run under the site's IP?

It appears that flask runs a private network but in same time `public_html` run under another network.
I want to be able to access file from `public_html` in my Flask function.

Also the Python app has a path where is accessible like: `testdomain.com/test-app`, I want to restrict unauthorized or users that are not logged in to login page first before accessing application directly.

Comment: Mixing PHP and Python isn't a very good idea. Why do you want to do this?